# Dominating sets and treewidth

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parameterized-complexity

As input we are given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$ and are asked to find a dominating set of size **exactly** $k$ in $G$. This problem is clearly NP-hard, but does it become polynomial time solvable if we assume $G$ has bounded treewidth? For bounded treewidth graphs you can find a dominating set of size at most $k$ by dynamic programming, but does the problem become hard if you ask for a set of size exactly $k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every graph with a DS of size $\leq k$ has a DS of size exactly $k$ (assuming $k$ is bounded by the number of vertices) as every superset of a DS is itself a DS.